# How can I go through a list of numbers and compare it with an another list I am going through?

Tags: haskell

I want to input two strings, "Hello" and "Hi" for example, and I want to go through every element in the two strings simultaneously and compare every character one by one. The two strings length in the actual program should be 5, if a char is equal to the other, return true, otherwise return false.

The program I have in mind should see 'H' in "Hello" and 'H' from "Hi" and return true, then I want it to check the 'e' in "Hello" and the 'i' in "Hi" and return false. I want it to keep on doing that till there is nothing to compare. I think I might need to use recursion but I am not sure how to implement it in this program really.

I tried using `x:xs` with the maximum range of 5 so `[0..5]`, but it didn't work at all.

My code (not working):

```
uncurryingString :: String -> Int -> Char
uncurryingString a b = a !! b

match :: String -> String -> [Int] -> Bool 
match a b (x:xs)
            |   uncurryingString a [x+1 | x <- xs]  == uncurryingString b [x+1 | x <- xs]       = True
            |   otherwise                                                                       = False
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question because you say "the two strings length in the actual program should be 5," but "Hello" and "Hi" clearly don't have the same length.

Comment: What is the point of passing a list of numbers to the `match` function, in addition to just two strings?

Comment: providing 2 clear examples of input and expected output might help in clarifying the queestions.

Comment: @Julia I am so sorry! I used those as they seemed like easy examples, in the program it might be something like "Hello" and "Horse". I am so sorry for the confusion caused by my lack of explaination!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking about this way too complicated.

First, as a rule of thumb, you should **never** use `!!` (whether directly or via some helper – `uncurryingString` is in fact exactly the same as `!!` itself). If direct indexing is required, a list is not the right data structure. But very often direct indexing is *not* required, it's just what's customarily used in some other programming languages that don't have pattern matching to do it more elegantly.

In your application, you're deconstructing both strings in parallel. Well, you should express that with a pattern match:

```
match (a:as) (b:bs) (x:xs) = ...
```

And now you can simply compare `a` and `b` directly, no need for messing about with any list comprehensions or indexing operators. In the example input `"Hello"` and `"Hi"`, both `a` and `b` will be `'H'` here.

But you probably don't want to return `True` right there, because there's still the rest of the string to be matched. That's where recursion comes in.

Finally, you need to clauses in case not all of the input lists are nonempty. Try to figure that out yourself.

What you probably don't need at all is the extra `[Int]` argument `(x:xs)`. It *could* make sense to have a depth-limiting argument, but that could be simply an `Int`. You would then do something like

```
match :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Bool
match _ _ 0 = True    -- lists are equal up to the specified max depth
match (a:as) (b:bs) n = ...
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful answer. I have a question though, it looks like you still kept the Int, which implies that i still need it. How is it useful if i am not using the indexing operator? and how will i be able to manipulate it?

Comment: I mean, it depends what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to compare the whole lists no matter how long they are, then you don't need any `Int` argument. (But then you should perhaps just use `==` on the entire lists...) If you want to abort after a certain depth, e.g. to not compare more than 5 elements from each list, then you can use that argument and decrement it in each recursive call. (But the same could be accomplished with an unlimited comparison and beforehand simply trimming the list to the desired max depth, using `take`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I already trim and only take 5 characters in everything with a function i made before. So i think i will try removing the ```Int``` argument. I would have used the ```==``` on the entire list, but i want to compare it character by character to see if the characters match or not. From my understanding if i use ```==``` it will check if the two string are the same or not, please correct me if what i said is completely wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: How about `zipWith (==) "Hello" "Hi"`?

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for!! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I recommend you anyway implement the full manually-recursive version (with and without depth limit) as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension is often a good way to compute things in Haskell, but not in this particular case.

I could try this code:

```
 [a==b | a <- "Hello", b <- "Hi"]
```

What does this do? You might think that this returns True, because the 'H' letters match - or you might thing that this returns False, because the other letters don't match. In fact, it does both - in effect, it is running multiple nested loops.

```
[True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

So, the takeaway is to use list comprehensions when you want nested loops, or just working through one dataset. Here we just want a single loop that works through the two words in parallel. Hence it must be recursion.

Comment: mentioning the `and` function in your answer may be a good idea

Comment: I think what the OP wants is actually side-by-side consumption of the lists, rather than all combinations. The can't be done with a standard list comprehension, but it is possible by either zipping the lists first `[a==b | (a,b) <- zip "Hello" "Hi"]` or using the `-XParallelListComp` extension as `[a==b | a <- "Hello" | b <- "Hi"]`.